# Look what is calling the initialize method of a class

Tags: ruby, class, initialization

So I have a too much code to post, and I have googled but dont found any solution.

I have a class e.g:

```
class Example
  def initialize
    #some_code
    p "class was initialized"
  end
end
```

The console prints "class was initialized" two times, and I can only find one line where the class gets initialized. My question is, if there are some methods to look from where the initialize method of the class is called, so I can find out why its initialized two times.

Comment: Try raising an exception when the class is initialized - then you can see exactly where is was called, by looking at the stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Example
  def initialize
    #some_code
    p "class was initialized"
    puts caller_locations
  end
end
```

In legacy Ruby:

```
class Example
  def initialize
    #some_code
    p "class was initialized"
    puts caller
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, the method caller is exactly what I was looking for, so I will mark yours as correct

Answer (score 1):

You can raise/catch an exception, which will get you access to stacktrace.

```
class Example
  def initialize

    begin
      raise
    rescue => e
      puts e.backtrace
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, your and sawas answer are both good and helped me to find out why it was called two times.